# Integral of a Trigonometric Expression $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sqrt[3]{\tan x}}{\left(\sin x + \cos x\right)^2} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals

This is from the finals of 2023 MIT Integration Bee: $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sqrt[3]{\tan x}}{(\sin x + \cos x)^2} \, dx$$
I've attempted to simplify the expression, but I'm having trouble finding a suitable method to integrate it. Any suggestions on how to approach this integral and evaluate it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: If anyone else can solve this without using beta function, I'll really appreciate it.

Comment: Take $u = \tan(x)$ and then a keyhole contour should be worth giving a shot.

Comment: thanks for the advice

Comment: why is it closed?

Comment: I know it's not an easy problem, but you still need to show an attempt for solving it.

Comment: Beta function and Legendre worked out for me pretty well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sqrt[3]{\tan{x}}}{(\sin{x} + \cos{x})^{2}} \ dx = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sqrt[3]{\tan{x}}}{\cos^{2}{x}(\tan{x} + 1)^{2}} \ dx \stackrel{u = \tan{x}}{=}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u^{1/3}}{(u+1)^{2}} \ du$$
$$= \textbf{B}(4/3,2/3) = \Gamma(4/3)\Gamma(2/3) = \frac{3}{2}\Gamma(1)\Gamma(4/3)\Gamma(5/3)$$
where $\textbf{B}(x,y)$ is the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Other_identities_and_formulas). Using the [Legendre formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem#Gamma_function%E2%80%93Legendre_formula),
$$\Gamma(1)\Gamma(4/3)\Gamma(5/3) = (2\pi)(3^{-5/2})\Gamma(3) = \frac{4\sqrt{3}\pi}{27}$$
Therefore,
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sqrt[3]{\tan{x}}}{(\sin{x} + \cos{x})^{2}} \ dx = \frac{2\sqrt{3} \pi}{9}$$

Comment: I made no mistake. Thats what I did in the final line. I only looked at $\Gamma(1)\Gamma(4/3)\Gamma(5/3)$ giving $4\sqrt{3} \pi / 27$ then multiplied the $3/2$ in the final line.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an elementary take as you wished. However, the handwork is quite extensive. Hence, the beta function would be more feasible.

$$\int^{\pi/2}_{0}{\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{\tan{x}}}{(\sin{x} + \cos{x})^2}}dx 
\\= \int^{\pi/2}_{0}{\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{\tan{x}}}{1 + \sin{2x}}}dx 
\\\xrightarrow{t \space= \space \tan{x}} \int^{+\infty}_{0}{\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{t}}{1 + \dfrac{2t}{1 + t^2}}} \cdot \dfrac{dt}{1 + t^2} 
\\= \int^{+\infty}_{0}{\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{t}}{(1 + t)^2}}dt$$

Using IBP, with $v = \sqrt[3]{t}$ and $du = \dfrac{dt}{(1 + t)^2}$,

$$\Rightarrow \int^{+\infty}_{0}{\sqrt[3]{t} \cdot\dfrac{dt}{(1 + t)^2}} 
=  \left. \dfrac{-\sqrt[3]{t}}{1 + t}\right|_0^{+\infty} + \int^{+\infty}_{0}{\dfrac{1}{3t^{2/3}} \cdot \dfrac{dt}{1 + t}}$$

We have $\left. \dfrac{-\sqrt[3]{t}}{1 + t}\right|_0^{+\infty} = 0$. Then, let $w^2 = t^{2/3}$, $w \cdot dw = \dfrac{dt}{3t^{1/3}}$

$$\Rightarrow \int^{+\infty}_{0}{\dfrac{1}{3t^{2/3}} \cdot \dfrac{dt}{1 + t}}
=\int^{+\infty}_{0}{\dfrac{dt}{3t^{1/3}} \cdot \dfrac{1}{t^{1/3} + t^{4/3}}}
=\int^{+\infty}_{0}{\dfrac{w \cdot dw}{w + w^4}}
\\=\int^{+\infty}_{0}{\dfrac{dw}{(1 + w)(1 - w + w^2)}}
\\=\dfrac{1}{3}\int^{+\infty}_{0}{\dfrac{1}{1 + w} - \dfrac{w - 2}{1 - w + w^2}} dw
\\=\dfrac{1}{3}\int^{+\infty}_{0}{\dfrac{1}{1 + w} - \dfrac{(2w - 1) - 3}{2(1 - w + w^2)}} dw
\\=\dfrac{1}{3}\int^{+\infty}_{0}{\dfrac{1}{1 + w} - \dfrac{2w - 1}{2(1 - w + w^2)} + \dfrac{3}{2(w  - 1/2)^2 + 3/4}}dw
\\=\lim\limits_{k \to +\infty}{\left.\left( \ln{(w + 1)} - \dfrac{1}{2}\ln(1 - w + w^2) + \dfrac{\sqrt{3}\arctan{\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}(2w - 1)}{3}\right)}}{3}\right)\right|_0^{k}}
\\=\lim\limits_{k \to +\infty}{\left.\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\ln\left(1 + \dfrac{3w}{1 - w + w^2}\right) + \dfrac{\sqrt{3}\arctan{\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}(2w - 1)}{3}\right)}}{3}\right)\right|_0^{k}}
\\=\dfrac{1}{2}\ln\left(1 + 0\right) + \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \cdot \dfrac{\pi}{2} - \left(\dfrac{1}{2}\ln\left(1 + 0\right) + \dfrac{\sqrt{3}\arctan{\left(\dfrac{-\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)}}{3}\right)
\\= \dfrac{2\pi\sqrt{3}}{6} + \dfrac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{18} 
\\= \dfrac{2\pi\sqrt{3}}{9}$$